# How do I remove this radiator cover?

Tags: repair, radiator

I'm currently in the process of decorating and making my new home look nice and 
a big thing that is bothering me is the dust from inside the radiator vent, there is a lot!

The radiator cover is meant to come off, but I think it has been fitted wrongly. No matter what I try I can't seem to get this cover off.

According to this [PDF-Document](http://www.expressradiant.ca/pdfs/product_compact_cleaning_how_to.pdf), I should be able to to remove it quite easily.

I'm getting frustrated, can someone tell me how I can remove this or confirm that it is poorly fitted.

[image: Radiator]
^This is the side view. As you can see the assembling is preventing the freedom of movement.
[image: Radiator]

The brand is [Stelrad](http://www.stelrad.com/).

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? Looks like  it's an integral part of the unit as manufactured.

Comment: Keshlam, I'm 100% sure it comes off. I unclipped it all the way around and there are some finger bolt type things keeping it on.

Comment: "confirm that it is poorly fitted"  **how do we do that?** "No matter what I try"  OK **what have you tried?**